# Cannot insert the value in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, mysql-insert-id

As i'm trying to insert the value in database through php code but it didn't work and also it didn't give any error. Here is the code that i'd tried to execute but not succeeded.

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "password", "project") or die("couldn't connect to the database");
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])) {
    header("location:index.php");
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        if ($_GET['e1'] == "E-LN3465") {
            $productname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['e1']);
            if ($insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO `cart`(`ID`, `pid`) ((Select `ID` from `users` where `Username`='$username'),(Select `pid` from `product` where `pname`='$productname'))")) {
                $checkQuery = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `cart`(`ID`, `pid`) ((Select `ID` from `users` where `Username`='$username'),(Select `pid` from `product` where `pname`='$productname'))");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Execute query two time  and `$db` is nothing in your code just remove it form your code

Comment: @Calimero no need of `values` in INSERT SELECT statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Saty you're right, my bad, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Calimero you'r welcome! we all learner here !!

Comment: @Saty but it still didn't work.

Comment: echo and Run your in phpmyadmin and check the erroe

Comment: No error.Also, it is not inserting.

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost","admin","password","project") or die("couldn't connect to the database");

error_reporting(0);

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
 header("location:index.php");
} else {

$username=$_SESSION['sess_user'];

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{


if( $_GET['e1']== "E-LN3465")
{$productname=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['e1']);
if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `cart`(`ID`, `pid`) ((Select `ID` from `users` where `Username`='$username'),(Select `pid` from `product` where `pname`='$productname'))")) 
{         echo "INSERT SUCESSFULLY";   }
}


}}

Comment: @Saty Now it is working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$mysqli` variable store your connection object and you are executing your query two time. `$db` is nothing in your code just remove it

```
if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `cart`(`ID`, `pid`) ((Select `ID` from `users` where `Username`='$username'),(Select `pid` from `product` where `pname`='$productname'))")) {
         echo "INSERT SUCESSFULLY";
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Change your query to

```
INSERT INTO `cart`(`ID`, `pid`)
SELECT users.ID, product.pid 
     FROM users, product
     WHERE users.Username='$username'
     AND product.pname='$productname';
```